# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ')'

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the following error when WordPress theme is installed:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ')' in /home.....header.php on line 51

and this is the line 51 code:

```
if( !empty( $onepage == 'one_page' ) || !empty($corpex_opt ['corpex_header_layout'] == '3' )){ ...
```

I will be happy if someone help.

Comment: What is this line **supposed** to do?

Comment: `empty` has to take a variable as parameter to check if there is something inside. You are passing an equality test as parameter, which will always answer a primitive value `true` or `false`. This is not a variable and cannot be checked for empty

Comment: I heard empty function wrong. this time I upgrade php version 5.6,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `empty` function wrong. [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) functions takes only one parameter

It should be something like this

```
if((!empty( $onepage )&&($onepage=='one_page')) 
    || (!empty($corpex_opt ['corpex_header_layout'] )  
    && ($corpex_opt ['corpex_header_layout']==3)) ) {
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.but looks there is my php version problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You should close parentheses before `== '3'`

change `!empty($corpex_opt ['corpex_header_layout'] == '3' )` to `!empty($corpex_opt ['corpex_header_layout'] ) == '3'`

Comment: `empty` answers `true` or `false` and will never be equal to `'3'`, this is a strange answer (edit: in a sense, true can be non-strictly equal to '3', but it's obvious that it's not the expected behaviour for this condition)

Comment: @Kaddath oh yes, you are right...I paid attention to the structure